# Facebook open graph object ,,, can't set its properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have successfully post the object on my wall with its default values for the properties.

What I need to do now is setting these properties for that object manually through my code.

Here is what I have done:

```
@protocol OGApple<FBOpenGraphAction>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;

@end

@protocol OGEatAction<FBOpenGraphAction>

@property (retain, nonatomic) id<OGApple> apple;

@end
```

the object "apple" here has four required properties (url, title, image, description) ,,, here is how I set them :

Define the object:

```
id<OGApple> graphObject = (id<OGApple>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
```

Define the action:

```
id<OGEatAction> action = (id<OGEatAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
```

set the properties (I have try method 1 and two) none of them set the object property :

Method one:

```
[graphObject setObject:@"The Game" forKey:@"title"];
[graphObject setObject:@"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png" forKey:@"image"];
[graphObject setObject:@"http://samples.ogp.me/267255650070428" forKey:@"url"];
```

Method two:

```
graphObject.url = @"http://samples.ogp.me/267255650070428";
graphObject.title = @"Mohammad";
graphObject.image = @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png";
```

then assign the object to the action:

```
action.apple = graphObject;
```

then POST the request

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/theapp:eat"
                                       graphObject:action
                                 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                     id result,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     // handle the result
                                     if(error)
                                         NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                     else
                                         NSLog(@"%@", result);
                                 }];
```

The request successfully posted and return id = xxxxxxxxxx

But on my timeline the object not take the parameters that I have passed to it!

Did I miss something or need any extra config on a server?

Thanks in advance :)